# Apple analytics API without using third party

Tags: angularjs, web, app-store, app-store-connect, analytics

I have my app uploaded on app store. I want to show its analytics data on my website (installed count, uninstall count etc). For this I have linked my appstore account with [appfigures.com](https://appfigures.com/).It works fine.

With this I have also integrated [this](https://github.com/JanHalozan/iTunesConnectAnalytics). But as I have enabled (I am not able to off it) the two factor authentication of my appstore account. So it is not allowing me to log in. So, now I don't want to use any third party tool. So is there any apple analytics API which I can use to show total downloads etc?